# Firebase authWithCustomToken stopped working for me after the version 2.2.1

Tags: objective-c, firebase

I have a fairly basic setup where the Firebase auth is called in the Manager singleton class init:

```
Firebase *fBase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://myfirebaseurl.com/"];
[fBase authWithCustomToken:accessToken withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAuthData *authData) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Auth Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Auth OK");
    }
}];
```

I have confirmed that the accessToken is available at the time of this call. In fact, the call has always worked fine while I was using some older version of Firebase. Yesterday, I decided to update to a latest one, and this simply stopped working. If I regress back to Firebase version 2.2.1, this call works fine. I have noticed that if I wait for very long time, the completion block is eventually called, after 10 minutes or so. I have also noticed that I can 'force' this call to work if I make a subseqent call about 2 second later. In that case, only the completion block from that 2nd call is being called. Needless to say, this feels very hacky and unreliable, so I decided to just use older version for the time being. But I'm thinking I must be doing something wrong, as something this fundamental can't really be broken in Firebase for almost a year?

Something else to note: I've tried making just a single auth call with a 2 second delay - no luck. It really needs two calls, and the second one to be with a 1-2s delay.